# Resource binding inside Data Binding expression ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this databinding expression:

```
  <%# (Boolean.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HasFoo").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

I want to use an asp.net resource binding tag for "yes" and "no," so that in other languages I can use the correct language (I know, I know, mostly everyone uses yes and no but this is just an example).

I've tried putting in

```
 "<%$ Resources: General, Yes %>"
```

It is in an item template:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <%# (Boolean.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HasFoo").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

But it seems I can't do that inside the databinding expression.  Anyone have any ideas other than loading these resources at page_init and then hiding them in a serverside hidden panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve any static Resource value using:

[GetLocalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms149953.aspx):

```
<%= HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(virtualPath, resourceKey, CultureInfo) %>
```

[GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149949.aspx):

```
<%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey, CultureInfo) %>
```

Take a look here for more information: [How to: Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Doesnt' work inside an eval it seems. I'm not doing this in the code behind, but rather on the client side aspx page.

Comment: This work inside aspx. How are you calling it? Could you show here?

Comment: <%# (Boolean.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HasFoo").ToString())) ? HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(virtualPath, resourceKey, CultureInfo).ToString() : HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(virtualPath, resourceKey, CultureInfo).ToString() %> or the another method. This should work!

Comment: Spot on my man!  Thanks!  You must not need the asp.net directives inside the evals!